# how to match a year range (string) argument eg. 2001-2002 in django urls by using regex

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x

I am getting a string value from Django form which I want to map to a URL. I tried with regex but it gives an error.

I tried below URL pattern to match: year/2006-2007

```
re_path(r'year/(?P<clg_year>.+?+)/', view.get_details, name="year")
```

I am making a reverse call in one of the view function:

```
clg_year = xyz_form.cleaned_data.get("clg_year")

return redirect(
    reverse("college:year", args=(clg_year))
```

)

Please note that the value 2006-2007 is a string that I am getting in some of the forms.

**The error I am getting is:**

*Reverse for 'year' with arguments '('2', '0', '0', '6', '-', '2', '0', '0', '7')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['year/(?P[\w-]+)/']*

Comment: Can you show *where* you use this pattern? So where you make a reverse call?

Comment: I am making a reverse call in one of the view function:

Comment: please [edit] your question and include (relevant parts) of your view function.

Comment: I have edited question with reverse call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the URL pattern more restrictive to only accept four digits followed by a dash followed by again four digits:

```
re_path(r'year/(?P<clg_year>\d{4}[-]\d{4})/', view.get_details, name="year")
```

But this will not solve the problem, since that is not related to the `re_path` definition itself, but due to calculating the URL based on a view name and parameters.

In your `reverse` call, you need to pass a *tuple* (well actually any iterable is fine) to the `args` parameter. By passing a string however, Django will iterate over the string, and consider these independent elements.

You thus should wrap it in a singleton tuple:

```
return redirect(
    reverse('college:year', args=(clg_year,))
)
```

Note that using `reverse(..)` is *not* necessary here. Indeed [**`redirect(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) can call `redirect(..)` internally. You thus can simply make a call to redirect with:

```
return redirect('college:year', clg_year)
```

or even more descriptive:

```
return redirect('college:year', clg_year=clg_year)
```

`redirect(..)` does not make use of `args=...` and `kwargs=...` but of positional and named parameters instead.

Comment: Thank you very much "Willem Van Onsem" for a descriptive answer. I have already solved the problem by adding a comma to reverse call argument (by making a tuple). I will use redirect instead of reverse.